# Nginx redirect to different domain only for specific query

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm basically trying to have nginx redirect:

```
https://website1.com/program_video/programXXX.mp4
```

to

```
http://website2.com/ProgramsVideos/programXXX.mp4
```

Given that "XXX" is the id of the video and might change.

I've been wandering around stackoverflow and nginx directory but wasn't able to get anything to work.
Last thing I tried was:

```
rewrite "https://website1.com/program_video/([a-zA-Z0-9]{23})\.mp4)$" http://website2.com/ProgramsVideos/$1 permanent;
```

But it doesn't redirect anything...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The regular expression does not require the scheme and host name. Try: `rewrite "^/program_video(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{23}\.mp4)$" http://website2.com/ProgramsVideos$1 permanent;`

Comment: Same result unfortunately, which is no redirection happens